# Solution to geometric Brownian motion with time dependent volatility and drift?

Tags: stochastic-calculus, geometric-brownian

I am able to compute the general solution of a standard geometric Brownian motion, but I'm struggling to find the general solution for a GBM where volatility and mean depend on time, $$\text{d}S_t = \mu(t) S_t\text{d}t+\sigma(t) S_t\text{d}W_t.$$

The general solution for a standard geometric Brownian, $\text{d}S_t = \mu S_t\text{d}t+\sigma S_t\text{d}W_t$ can be computed by firstly separating the variables $\frac{\text{d}S_t}{S_t} = \mu \text{d}t+\sigma \text{d}W_t$, then taking integration on both sides $\int\frac{\text{d}S_t}{S_t} = \int \mu dt+\sigma dW_t$. Since $\frac{\text dS_t}{S_t}$ links to the derivative of $\ln(S_t)$, the proceeding step constitutes the Itô calculus and results in $\ln(S_t) = (\mu - \frac{1}{2} \sigma^2)t + \sigma W_t$. Then taking exponential on both sides and plugging in the initial condition $S(0)$ we obtain the analytical solution $S(t) = S(0) e^{(\mu - \frac{1}{2} \sigma^2)t+ \sigma W_t}$

However, when $\mu$ and $\sigma$ are time dependent $\text{d}S_t = \mu(t) S_t\text{d}t+\sigma(t) S_t\text{d}W_t$, the solution is totally different and I tried applying the same methods I used in a standard geometric Brownian motion but the solution is not correct. I have found some material online but it doesn't seem to make sense to me ... I am able to continue up until integrating on both sides, then after that I don't know what to do.

Comment: What about the mean and the variance of $S_t$ if $\mu$ is a constant AND $\sigma$ is linear in time ? (for example : $\mu = 0.06$ and $\sigma(t) = 0.01t$)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the generalised geometric Brownian motion
$$\text{d}S_t = \mu(t)S_t \text{d}t+\sigma(t)S_t \text{d}W_t.$$

Using [Itô's Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It%C3%B4%27s_lemma), you get
$$\text{d}\ln(S_t) = \left(\mu(t)-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2(t)\right)\text{d}t+\sigma(t) \text{d}W_t.$$
Thus, by definition of an SDE,
$$\ln(S_t) =\ln(S_0)+\int_0^t \left(\mu(s)-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2(s)\right)\text{d}s+\int_0^t\sigma(s) \text{d}W_s.$$
Thus,
$$S_t =S_0\exp\left(\int_0^t \left(\mu(s)-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2(s)\right)\text{d}s+\int_0^t\sigma(s) \text{d}W_s\right).$$
You cannot simplify these integrals without assuming what your drift and variance are. You can however compute moments of the stock price, etc. The process is still log-normally distributed.

Comment: Thanks @Kevin, that is actually what I want to do, I am doing this for project in mathematical modelling module I study at my final year bachelor's studies. I notice that $\mu(t)$ changes to $\mu(s)$, could you clarify what does 's' represent? Is it same as t (time) but different notation?

Comment: Oh sorry, I just realised that 's' must be the values of mu and sigma that change at everytime step. Thanks though!

Comment: @PlatinumMaths I hope you enjoy your modelling module :) The $s$ is just an integral dummy variable. You can use $u$ or $\tau$ instead (or whatever really). The point is that $S_t$ contains integrals that go from $0$ to $t$ (depend on the entire history of the path up to time $t$). Thus, the integrals of the drift and volatility need to have another variable, other than $t$. By default, I picked $s$. It's like writing $t^2 = 2\int_0^t s\text{d}s$. Makes sense?

Comment: yeah makes sense, Thank you so much! God bless!

Comment: hey what is the idea behind simulating stocks with time dependent mu and sigma? Would it be the case of using a random mu and sigma at each time step?

Comment: Hey, you can make $\mu$ and $\sigma$ random, yes. Look for example for stochastic volatility model. You may first want to revise some stochastic calculus though. A time dependent mean could for example model seasonal patterns...

Comment: yeah that probably a good idea! Cheers!

Comment: Could you please let me know how we can specify a suitable diffusion term and drift term when they are time-dependent?

Comment: @user53249 depends on what you mean with "suitable"? Subject to some constraints (to ensure the SDE has a strong solution), you can choose _any arbitrary_ function of time.

Comment: For example, I want to model cash inflow from revenue using a time-dependent Geometric Brownian motion. In this case, drift term and diffusion term are deterministic functions of time but unknown. If we find the analytical solution of the process, we will end up with an integral expression for the drift term and diffusion term (Applying Ito lemma).

Comment: Now, imagine that we aim to make a prediction for the future, then after fitting the model and checking for the accuracy of the model, we need to simulate paths for the future to see how well our model works. In this case, we need to consider a dynamic for the expected value (like a mean-reverting model) to replace the unknown expression with a specific expression characterized by additional parameters. That is why I am asking how we can distinguish the form of diffusion and drift term function.